# make virtualenvwrapper to work with different python versions

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

#### fix: sorry, all is fine, error was because of no module installed in this new environment, `jinja2`.

First time using `virtualenvwrapper` so I am little confused.

Setup went fine, I read the docs, but still I don't understand few things.

In my `.bashrc` file I've set:

```
# virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Snakepit
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I already have my project files, so I thougt I should do the following:

Go into `~/Snakepit/` directory, run `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 [ envname ]`

(I need this specific version for my project), and I saw it created in
`~/.virtualenvs/` dir.

My command promt changes showing me that my new environment is `[ envname ]`.

When I do now: `python -V`, it shows that I am using version 2.7 of python, so
all is well!

But when I move now, my project files into `Snakepit` directory, and try
running my program with `python myprogram.py` it shows me errors because it
still tries to run my program with `python 3`.

How is that possible when `python -V` shows `version 2.7`?

Answer (score 0):

Error was not about python version being run, but instead module missing in newly created environment. I will leave it, for a feature reference.